# Assembler,правильно ли я делаю замену в слове?

Tags: ассемблер

Делаю в TASM, появился вопрос т.к не уверен в правильности кода
Вот задание 
В сегменте данных размещены последовательно числа:-1, 2,+128,129,+32769 в минимально необходимом для них формате. Расширить два первых числа до формата слова и записать следом за исходными числами. НА МЕСТО СТАРШЕГО БАЙТА ТРЕТЬЕГО ЧИСЛА ЗАПИСАТЬ СИМВОЛ '#',НА МЕСТО МЛАДШЕГО ЕГО БАЙТА - СИМВОЛ '1'.

```
.386
dseg segment use16
a db -1
b db 2
c dw +128
d dd +32769
ea dw ?
eb dw ?
ec dw ?
ed dd ?
dseg ends 

cseg segment use16
assume ds:dseg, cs:cseg
; загрузка регистров-указателей 
m1:
mov cx, dseg
mov ds, cx
; расширим первые два числа до формата слова
movzx ax, ds:[a]
movzx bx, ds:[b]
mov ds:ea,ax
mov ds:eb,bx
; Заменим 3 число, максимальный байт на решетку, минимальный на 1
;ТУТ У МЕНЯ ВОПРОС!!!
mov cx, ds:c
mov ch,'#'
mov cl,'1'
; Завершение исполнения
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
cseg ends
end m1
```

Comment: А запустить и проверить вам что мешает?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов у меня просто получается, что ds:000C (там где третье число, становится равно 0). Вот и получается, что вроде как код не совсем верно работает, а где ошибка я не знаю

Comment: Отладчик используйте...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну вот в TD так и получается ,что у меня почему то в этом адресе памяти значение 0.

Comment: Вот у вас последовательность команд: `mov cx, ds:c; mov ch,'#'; mov cl,'1'` (точка с запятой тут просто разделитель). Вы считали данные в регистр, заменили старший и младший байты, и так в регистре и оставили. Дальше у вас "завершение исполнения". Каким образом, по-вашему, в памяти в переменной `ec` что-то появится?

Answer (score 1):

```
.386
dseg segment use16
a db -1
b db 2
c dw +128
d dd +32769
ea dw ?
eb dw ?
ec dw ?
ed dd ?
dseg ends 

cseg segment use16
assume ds:dseg, cs:cseg
; загрузка регистров-указателй сегментов ds и es
m1:
mov cx, dseg
mov ds, cx
; расширим первые два числа до формата слова,   запишем в es:ea
movzx ax, ds:[a]
movzx bx, ds:[b]
mov ds:ea,ax
mov ds:eb,bx
; Заменим 3 число максимум на решетку, минимум на 1
mov ch,'#'
shl cx,8
mov cl,'1'
mov ds:ec,cx
; Завершение исполнения
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h
cseg ends
end m1
```